# Google Adsense ads not displaying images

Tags: image, ads, adsense

The ads are displayed but the multiplex ads are showing text only and not displaying images.
[image]

I just updated my [ads.txt](https://webcodingcenter.com/ads.txt) file, but it has not been updated on Google's records apparently. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I do see visual advertisings on your website...

Comment: @rabsom Really? That's weird. I am not seeing any graphic ads even after clearing the cache and cookies on my browsers.

Comment: @rabsom I am referring to the multiplex ads. The other types of ads are working here too.

Comment: not sure where to experience this multiplex ads on your website.

Comment: @rabsom try navigating to more pages. the multiplex ads would show up occassionally.